# How to go to Back Screen in React Native

Tags: android, react-native

Sir I want to go to the Login Screen from Home Screen  drawer side menu.

Splash=> Login=> Homepage and when I Logout I want to go to Login page. I use the bellow code:

```
navigateToLoginPage = () => {

    //const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_USER_ID",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_FULL_NAME",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_CON_CODE",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_MOBILE",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_EMAIL",'');

    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_VEHICLE",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_DUTY_STATUS_ID",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_POI",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_POA",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_ON_DUTY",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_PROFILE_PIC",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_CUR_LOC",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_CUR_LAT",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_CUR_LONG",'');
    SharedPreferences.setItem("BOY_STATUS_NAME",'');

    Toast.show('LogOut Sucessfully', Toast.LONG);

    (async () => {

        await delay(1000);

        // Executed 100 milliseconds later
        this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginPage')

    })();
};
```

Comment: Are you facing any error?? If yes can you mention that.

Comment: I am Not getting any error & it is not redirecting to Login Page

Comment: @wasim Can you please share your navigator also

Comment: In Login i use to navigate
export default createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        LoginPage:Login_Page,
        call_drawer:Call_drawer
    },
    {
        initialRouteName:'LoginPage'
    }
)

Comment: The code which you provided was Native android code right?? From there you can't use `this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginPage')`.

Comment: Yes Sir  this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginPage') was Native code; LoginPage I declared in Login Page.

Comment: In Native how can you use `this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginPage')`?

Comment: When I want to navigate I use this.props.navigation.navigate('here the initialRouteName'); If any other way to navigate between page please say me i can use that also because I am fresher in react native so please help me.